# Working of MongoDB's implicit collection access on calling db.<collection>

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

In MongoDB, when we access a collection on a db object, if the collection is undefined, it implicitly calls the getCollection function defined in DB.prototype.

I am not able to figure out where this call happens in the Mongo shell source: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo/shell

How does this work?

Comment: It works pretty similar to browser javascript execution. In Mongo, V8 is the engine which runs javascript queries issued on mongo shell. Ref [https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/release-notes/2.4-javascript/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As at MongoDB 3.4, the `mongo` shell integrates with a scripting engine API that is part of the MongoDB server code base. The default collection behaviour is implemented by overriding the `getProperty` method of the `db` object: [src/mongo/scripting/mozjz/db.cpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v3.4/src/mongo/scripting/mozjs/db.cpp#L92).

I don't believe there is an equivalent approach to doing this sort of autoloading in pure JavaScript, as the only default JavaScript method available is the class constructor.